# In-app purchase and subscriptions in android apps

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

Can we have in-app purchase and subscription options in android apps? If yes, how do we implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try MoVend:https://movend.com/. It provides different purchase options like paypal, in-app billing, etc.

Comment: @techno you can start by downloading the SDK from https://movend.com/sdk and check the integration guide and sample source code within it.

Answer (score 7):

Subscriptions are now supported with in-app billing.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Answer (score 4):

It's called In-App Billing on Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

I don't believe it supports a subscription model if you use this system.

Comment: Is there a way to have a subscription model?

Comment: I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

Bachbill supports in-app billing for Android. We implemented it using Tic-tac-to as an example and the code and more information are available in this link: 
http://wiki.bachbill.com/confluence/display/devreference/Android+example+3.+Adding+In-app-purchase+to+the+Tic-tac-toe+game

Comment: But doesn't that violate the  Android Terms of service?