# Is it possible with android in-app purchase monthly subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, subscription, in-app-billing

I found [Another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759096/in-app-purchase-and-subscriptions-in-android-apps), but i'm not sure if it answers my question.

I want my application to be found on market, but i also want the users to use in-app purchase with a monthly description.

I found this:[Android Subscriptions and license fees](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140504)

So if i use MoVend, i can't distribute it on Android market?
Are there any solutions to this, so i can distribute it on the Android market AND use in-app monthly subscription?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a business problem, not a coding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make a monthly subscription, because if google catches you (which they will), your application will be permanently removed and banned from marked.

> Add subscriptions & recurring charges
>
> With subscriptions, you can add products that charge users for content
>   or services on a recurring basis. You can offer multiple subscriptions
>   within the same app.
>
> To add recurring charges and subscription billing to your apps, you'll
>   need to use the Google Play In-app billing API.

[Source](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140504)

Comment: "Please note that collecting payments through your application is not allowed under the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement."

Comment: What if I collect the payment from Google market but manage the subscription through my content server?

Comment: You can go the source link @JanDragsbaek provided, right now google has changed the policy and monthly subscription is allowed.

Comment: have you any demo or demo link of it ? please give me because m new in this feature

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:

```
You can charge users on a monthly, seasonal (defined start and end dates), 
or annual basis for content or services.
```

Reference: [Add subscriptions & recurring charges](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en)